# UndefinedError: 'user' is undefined

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, jinja2

When I try to open users.html I got the mentioned error

> UndefinedError: 'user' is undefined

even though that I define it in friend route.

view.py

```
@app.route('/Users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Users():
users = User.query.all()
return render_template('Users.html', contact= users)

@app.route('/friend/<name>')
@login_required
def friend(name):
    user = User.query.filter_by(name = name).first()
    if user is None:
        flash('User %s not found.' % name)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if user == g.user:
        flash('You can\'t Friend yourself!')
        return redirect(url_for('Users', name = name, user=user))
    u = g.user.be_friend(user)
    if u is None:
        flash('Cannot Friend ' + name + '.')
        return redirect(url_for('Users', name = name, user=user))
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('You are now Friend with' + name + '!')
    return redirect(url_for('index', name=name, user=user))
```

User.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
   {% block content %}
     <h2>show all users</h2>
         {% for contact in contact  %}
            <strong>name:</strong><a href={{url_for('profile', id=contact.id)}}> 
           {{  contact.name}}</a><br>
           # Got error here eventhough I define user in friend route
           <a href="{{ url_for('friend', name= user.name) }}">Friend</a>
         {% endfor %}
       {% endblock %}
```

Comment: so if I delete <a href="{{ url_for('friend', name= user.name)}}">Friend</a> It  works So any help That how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `user.html` you call the variable `contact`. You probably want to call it `user`.

```
{% for user in contact %}
```

You'll also need to update the references to `contact.id` and `contact.name`.

Comment: Thanx I always have problem with this for can you give me a source to know about it more @dirn

Comment: The [Jinja docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for) go into some detail.